# Using Optaplanner's NearbySelection in a MoveIteratorFactory

Tags: optaplanner

Is it possible to take advantage of the Nearby Selection feature in a (custom) MoveIteratorFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'd have to write it yourself basically in your MoveIterator.

Nearby Selection uses the `Selector` lifecycle events. Although you could in theory reuse an EntitySelector(Config) to some degree, I fear you'll be lacking the necessary lifecycle events to do so correctly probably.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get a reference to the distance matrix created for the other moves?